# is there a Mercurial installer equivilant to VisualSVNServer?

Tags: windows, apache, mercurial

I am using windows 2003R2

VisualSVNServer installs and works easily.

I have been tasked with reviewing Mercurial, but I'm having trouble setting up the directory for Apache.

is there any equivialant of the VisualSVNServer installer for Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of one, but setting up hgwebdir was pretty simple.

[Step-by-step instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through it step by step again.  I know i can do it without the browser but it will simplify things in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a Mercurial **server**?

If you just want to share Mercurial repositories over your internal company network, you can just put the repos on a network share.

Of course, you don't have web access then, but you can manage permissions on the network share via Active Directory.

Comment: This really isn't a great idea. Mercurial is designed assuming fast local access if you're directly accessing the repository. If you're accessing a repo not on the local machine you're alwys going to be better off using a local clone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test Mercurial, it is as easy as just installing the command line (hg) and enable a directory with some files:

```
> hg init .
> hg add <file>
> hg commit -m"log msg"
```

Also if you want to play with cloning, multiple repositories etc, you could use the same initial repository and when inside it type "hg serve", which will launch a small hg server (no setup required!), then in an other windows, you can "hg clone", "hg pull", "hg push" etc.

Finally, if you need a company-wide installation managing multiple repos, then either you need to master hgwebdir, or else there is also a tool called "Mercurial Server" which might be easier to setup and does not requires Apache.

Comment: Sorry. Although Mercurial Server is written in Python, it is Unix-only.. (too many /etc-isms I guess). You can forget about it, sorry about that.